# ASP.NET MVC - Html.Action - passing DateTime data causing errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this:

```
@Html.Action("CheckForModifyPost", "Forums", new { postAuthor = item.Author.UserName, dateCreated = item.DateCreated})
```

And i get following error on this:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item
>   of type 'System.Int32'.

Both `item.Author.UserName` and `item.DateCreated` are not null, and all i know is that this has something to do with `item.DateCreated`. How can i fix this error?

Comment: please share the rest of your view. And explain how you're populating your values

Comment: Could you please show the signature of the Action you are calling (the parameter names must match) and also your relevant route mappings.

Comment: Just add your answer below and select it as correct to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
suppose your controller is as follow

ForumController.cs
[httpGet]
public void CheckForModifyPost(string postAuthor, DateTime dateCreated )
{
  YOUR CODE GOES HERE
}



@Html.Action("CheckForModifyPost", "Forums", new { postAuthor = item.Author.UserName, dateCreated = item.DateCreated})



so in @html.Action pass the value with same name as in your action method like if in action method "postAuthor" as argument than in @html.Action pass the value of that argument with same name as in action method means use "postAuthor" in your @html.Action,
if their is only one character different than error occure
```